# Sonar can be accessed locally but not accessed elsewhere

Tags: sonarqube

Just tried to install a standalone sonar 2.0.5 in Win XP.

```
Setting : 

IP   : 127.0.0.1
Port : 9000
WebContext : /
```

It can be accessed locally. However when I tried to access it from other computer, it cant be accessed. So I tried to change the setting to Port 8080 ( my tomcat port ) and shutdown my tomcat. Still not accessible. My Tomcat ( port 8080, if running ) is accessible via network. Windows firewall is off.

Any idea why this happens?

Comment: First, Sonar 2.0.5 does not exist. Second, have you modified the configuration of the standalone version? How do you start it? Please add more info to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've configured Sonar to bind to the local loopback address. Try changing the IP address to "0.0.0.0".

See the following for more details:

- [Difference between 0.0.0.0 and 127.0.0.1](https://serverfault.com/questions/78048/whats-the-difference-between-ip-address-0-0-0-0-and-127-0-0-1)