# Sonar installed & started but not accessible

Tags: sonarqube

Summary:

- Installed standalone sonar
- Started through /etc/init.d/sonar start
- sonar.log doesn't show any error
- unable to open http://mymachine.ipaddress:9000/sonar

  GET http://mymachine.ipaddress:9000/sonar net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

---

I am trying to run a standalone sonar on a remote machine running CentOS 6.5.

Following: http://sonar-pkg.sourceforge.net/ - installed through:

```
yum install sonar
```

I've set up a remote database connection to MySQL instance, already set up with the 'sonar' database and user as described in: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing

Modified `sonar.properties` configuration:

```
sonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://<mysql.ipaddress>:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
```

Initially - I only changed the jdbc connection, sonar started fine but I am unable to open sonar web http://mymachine.ipaddress:9000/

Based on:

- [Sonar can be accessed locally but not accessed elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896750/sonar-can-be-accessed-locally-but-not-accessed-elsewhere)
- [Unable to open remotely installed sonar on a browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114259/unable-to-open-remotely-installed-sonar-on-a-browser)

I updated more properties:

```
sonar.web.host=<mymachine.ipaddress>
sonar.web.context=/sonar
sonar.web.port=9000
```

and run sonar again

```
/etc/init.d/sonar start
```

Sonar started fine, but still unable to access it through browser.
Going to http://mymachine.ipaddress:9000/sonar gives: "This webpage is not available"

```
GET http://mymachine.ipaddress:9000/sonar net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

sonar.log:

> --> Wrapper Started as Daemon Launching a JVM... Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>
> 2014.10.01 14:30:18 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Xmx256m
>   -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.awt.headless=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer
>   /tmp/sq-process2719628111769939329properties
>   2014.10.01 14:30:18 WARN  sea[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting search
>   2014.10.01 14:30:18 INFO  sea[o.s.s.SearchServer]  Starting ES[sonarqube] on port: 9001
>   2014.10.01 14:30:18 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1412188217506] version[1.1.2], pid[329],
>   build[e511f7b/2014-05-22T12:27:39Z]
>   2014.10.01 14:30:18 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1412188217506] initializing ...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:18 INFO  sea[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1412188217506] loaded [], sites []
>   2014.10.01 14:30:20 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1412188217506] initialized
>   2014.10.01 14:30:20 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1412188217506] starting ...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:20 INFO  sea[o.e.transport]  [sonar-1412188217506] bound_address {inet[/0.0.0.0:9001]}, publish_address
>   {inet[/:9001]}
>   2014.10.01 14:30:23 INFO  sea[o.e.cluster.service]  [sonar-1412188217506] new_master
>   [sonar-1412188217506][k85f1MFxQgSy_aXegApX1g][CORPSTGCI01][inet[/:9001]]{rack_id=sonar-1412188217506},
>   reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
>   2014.10.01 14:30:23 INFO  sea[o.e.discovery]  [sonar-1412188217506] sonarqube/k85f1MFxQgSy_aXegApX1g
>   2014.10.01 14:30:25 INFO  sea[o.e.gateway]  [sonar-1412188217506] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
>   2014.10.01 14:30:25 INFO  sea[o.elasticsearch.node]  [sonar-1412188217506] started
>   2014.10.01 14:30:31 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
>   2014.10.01 14:30:31 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]:
>   /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.55.x86_64/jre/bin/java -Xmx768m
>   -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/sonar/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/opt/sonar/lib/jdbc/mysql/mysql-connector-java-5.1.27.jar
>   org.sonar.server.app.WebServer
>   /tmp/sq-process7956510077635803069properties
>   2014.10.01 14:30:32 WARN  web[o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint]  Starting web
>   2014.10.01 14:30:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Connectors]  HTTP connector is enabled on port 9000
>   2014.10.01 14:30:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Webapp]  Webapp directory: /opt/sonar/web
>   2014.10.01 14:30:33 INFO  web[o.e.plugins]  [sonar-1412188217506] loaded [], sites []
>   2014.10.01 14:30:34 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerImpl]  SonarQube Server / 4.5 / c8bb686cbee8e1dce3312ef253db76e7c0e3c0c7
>   2014.10.01 14:30:34 INFO  web[o.s.c.p.Database]  Create JDBC datasource for
>   jdbc:mysql://10.0.30.204:3306/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.DefaultServerFileSystem]  SonarQube home: /opt/sonar
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Findbugs / 2.4 /
>   a334be36ba4374bb779255272c53fb08675ac2c2
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Duplications / 4.5 /
>   c8bb686cbee8e1dce3312ef253db76e7c0e3c0c7
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Core / 4.5 / c8bb686cbee8e1dce3312ef253db76e7c0e3c0c7
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Java / 2.4 / 7e7e6335211bb9c0ff9727065f43e7010cc3df91
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Database Cleaner / 4.5 /
>   c8bb686cbee8e1dce3312ef253db76e7c0e3c0c7
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin English Pack / 4.5 /
>   c8bb686cbee8e1dce3312ef253db76e7c0e3c0c7
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Email notifications / 4.5 /
>   c8bb686cbee8e1dce3312ef253db76e7c0e3c0c7
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.ServerPluginJarsInstaller]  Deploy plugin Design / 4.5 / c8bb686cbee8e1dce3312ef253db76e7c0e3c0c7
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Install plugins done: 88 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.RailsAppsDeployer]  Deploy Ruby on Rails applications
>   2014.10.01 14:30:36 INFO  web[o.s.j.s.AbstractDatabaseConnector]  Initializing Hibernate
>   2014.10.01 14:30:38 INFO  web[o.s.s.p.UpdateCenterClient]  Update center: http://update.sonarsource.org/update-center.properties (no
>   proxy)
>   2014.10.01 14:30:38 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Code colorizer, supported languages: java
>   2014.10.01 14:30:39 INFO  web[o.s.s.n.NotificationService]  Notification service started (delay 60 sec.)
>   2014.10.01 14:30:39 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer]  Starting DB to Index synchronization
>   2014.10.01 14:30:39 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.BaseIndex]  Index rules:rules has last update of Wed Oct 01 13:39:50 EDT 2014
>   2014.10.01 14:30:42 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.BaseIndex]  Index rules:activeRules has last update of Wed Oct 01 13:40:01 EDT 2014
>   2014.10.01 14:30:42 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.BaseIndex]  Index logs:sonarLogs has last update of Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 EST 1969
>   2014.10.01 14:30:44 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.IndexSynchronizer]  Synchronization done in 5413ms...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:44 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy GWT plugins...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:44 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Deploy GWT plugins done: 0 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:44 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Load metrics...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterMetrics]  Cleaning quality gate conditions
>   2014.10.01 14:30:45 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Load metrics done: 441 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel]  Register technical debt model...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:45 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDebtModel]  Register technical debt model done: 31 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:45 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Register rules...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:47 INFO  web[org.sonar.INFO]  Register rules done: 2256 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:47 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles]  Register Quality Profiles...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.q.RegisterQualityProfiles]  Register Quality Profiles done: 2235 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters]  Register measure filters...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterNewMeasureFilters]  Register measure filters done: 4 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards]  Register dashboards...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterDashboards]  Register dashboards done: 9 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates]  Register permission templates...
>   2014.10.01 14:30:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RegisterPermissionTemplates]  Register permission templates done: 2 ms
>   2014.10.01 14:30:49 INFO  web[o.s.s.s.RenameDeprecatedPropertyKeys]  Rename deprecated property keys
>   2014.10.01 14:30:50 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  jruby 1.7.9 (ruby-1.8.7p370) 2013-12-06 87b108a on OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
>   1.7.0_55-mockbuild_2014_04_16_12_11-b00 [linux-amd64]
>   2014.10.01 14:30:50 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  using a shared (threadsafe!) runtime
>   2014.10.01 14:31:09 INFO  web[jruby.rack]  keeping custom (config.logger) Rails logger instance
>   2014.10.01 14:31:32 INFO  web[o.a.c.u.SessionIdGenerator]  Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took
>   [22,433] milliseconds.
>   2014.10.01 14:31:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.app.Logging]  Web server is started
>   2014.10.01 14:31:32 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same problem for `4.5`. I even downgraded to `4.4` and got the *same* issue.
As far as I can tell, the newer versions use elastic search and that part is totally broken.

I downgraded to version `4.3.3` and it started OK (and I didn't have to do anything special to not lose the existing data in my mysql db - from `4.3.2`)

Comment: The "elastic search part" is definitely not "totally broken", this is most probably an issue with e.g network (firewall?) or OS configuration. We have development machines on Mac OS, Ubuntu and Fedora that don't have any issue with starting SonarQube 4.4, 4.5 or even 5.0 for that matter.

Comment: @mith it certainly was broken for me. The logs says to delete /opt/sonar/conf/es (IIRC) which I did and it still blew up. The site got stuck at the "maintenance" redirect. I use Centos if that helps, installed using yum, and yes I go through a proxy (no choice), which is correctly configured in sonar.properties, but I fail to see why an internal usage of elastic search would need Internet anyway

Comment: There is no such need, so please come explain your issue to the SonarQube users mailing list, since StackOverflow is not really suited to in-depth investigation.

Comment: @mirh I just kept downgrading until it worked. I'm annoyed because broken distros (both released in the last week or so) wasted an hour of my life today. I'll post on a sonar forum tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed the logs in /logs and read connect refused to localhost:9092,
therefore I changed (first you must stop (Ctrl+C) Sonar Server) **sonar.jdbc.url** property in /conf/**sonar.properties**:

```
    Before:
    sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/sonar

    Modified:
    sonar.jdbc.url:                            jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1:9092/sonar
```

If you have other problems, you should deactivate Java 8 in Windows (Control Panel > Java > user tab and system tab) and close all windows of control panel, then restart Windows.

Other additional steps if it's necessary:

edit sonar-runner\conf\sonar-runner.properties

```
modified property:
sonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.1:9000
```